# Should "Here Document" ONLY be used after interactive command?

Tags: bash, xargs

I test the "Here Document" after a common command like ping, here is the situation:

[image: ping command can not use heredoc]

My Question is :
Can I ONLY use here document in interactive command like cat, ex and so on , but can not use it in non-interactive command like ping and some other command?

Comment: A here-document supplies data to standard input. So it only makes sense to use it if the command reads from standard input.

Comment: `cat` isn't really considered interactive, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I found lots of heredoc examples using cat ,like cat <<EOF hello world EOF, so I think it as a interactive command .

Comment: @Jim : An interactive command is a command, which is designed to read something from the user's input instead of a file. It could for instance read directly from /dev/tty.  If a program reads from stdin, the data can come from everywhere - typically from a file, Since stdin **can** be redirected to an interactive device (as it is the normal case in an interactive shell), usage of such programs interactively is possible,  but the interactivity is not a property of the command, but of the binding of stdin to an interactive device.

Comment: @user1934428 , Thank you for your explanation. know the  "interactive" much more now.

Comment: I consider "interactive" to refer to programs where there's a back-and-forth sequence of inputs and results, e.g. Emacs, vi, top, bc. If the program just reads continuous input, it's not really interactive. It's like the difference between a speech and a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` doesn't get its parameters from standard input, it only gets them from the command line arguments. If you want to turn input into arguments, you can use the `xargs` command:

```
xargs ping <<EOF
www.baidu.com
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I need to know the difference between command line arguments and standard input. Thank you!